# why am I getting the 'the operator && is undefined for the argument type(s) char,char' error

Tags: java, arrays, char, boolean

```
    if ((board[x][x] && board[x + 1][x + 1] && board[x + 2][x + 2]) == 'Y') {
            playerWins = true;
            }
```

Why can't I use && and || here?

Comment: What type is `board` variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want this:

```
if (board[x][x] == 'Y' && board[x + 1][x + 1] == 'Y' && board[x + 2][x + 2] == 'Y') {
    playerWins = true;
}
```

`&&` can only be used to join boolean expressions together.

Your code assumed some sort of distribution rule, like `(x && y) == z` being equivalent to `(x == z) && (y == z)`. In English, you can state things that way "If x and y are both z," but programming languages (and formal logic) don't have such a definition.

Answer (score 1):

Java logical operators perform operations on just boolean values. So the two operands of any logical operators need to be boolean. In your code, board[x][y] is of type char and so it throws an exception. You need to compare it to something or have something else which is boolean.
Same for board[x + 1][x + 1].
(Typed from phone)

Answer (score 0):

Java's conditional evaluation is different compared to other languages (like C, C++).

> Although loop conditions (if, while and the exit condition in for) in
>   Java and C++ both expect a boolean expression, code such as if(a = 5)
>   will cause a compile error in Java because there is no implicit
>   narrowing conversion from int to boolean.

Please refer the below link for details:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_Java_and_C%2B%2B

Answer (score 0):

You cannot concatenate these expressions to be evaluated with '&&' or '||', since they will not be evaluated to boolean, but here in this case to chars.

However, you can do this:

```
if (board[x][x] == 'Y' && board[x + 1][x + 1] == 'Y' && board[x + 2][x + 2] == 'Y') {
     playerWins = true;
}
```

or even this way:

```
/*so this methods check if the board has a different value than 'Y', so it returns false immediately without going over the other positions, otherwise if the value was equal to Y at all positions the if statement wont be accessed,  
you will exit the for-loop & return true;  You're main method must store the boolean value returned not more */

public static boolean winGame(PARAMS p) {  //you can give it the 2d array as a parameter for example..
   for(int x = 0; x < value; x++) {   // you specify the value according to your board
       if(board[x][x] != 'Y') {
             return false;
   }
      return true;
}
```